# How to share with Qt with other users on pc?

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu

I installed Qt as admin under the path /home/admin/Qt, when I log in to gnu/linux ubuntu under another user (user1) I can't launch QtCreator. How can I make this launch possible, for example by creating an icon on the user1 desktop?

I tried to copy /home/admin/.local/share/applications/org.qt-project.qtcreator.desktop to /home/user1/.local/share/applications/ and then copied org.qt* file to the user1 desktop, but the result was an unstartable file.

P.s. I'm super new in Linux.

Comment: If you are very new to Linux, and just need to get stuff done, have each user install their own Qt with the online installer. That way they can also control which Qt versions and platforms they need.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the access rights: you need to give read and execute access to `user1` group to the Qt directory.